# Click on button will change the visibility of buttons in list item from invisible to visible

Tags: android, android-listview

[image]

In the list Items, there is a button "delete" and textview.. on click of delete button in list item I am deleting that particular list item.. but My question is:that delete button is invisible at the start and when user click on "edit" button shown below at the top of the screen, I want to make all the buttons from invisible to visible.. But I am not getting how to implement that..

ListViewAdapater.java :

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public ArrayList<String> list;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    int count = 0;
    static int list_size;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        list_size = list.size();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        if (list == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return list_size;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        Log.i("Calling getItem()", "getItem()");
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        Log.i("Calling getItemId()", "getItemId()");
        return position;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView notes_text;

        static Button delete;
    }

    //  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i("ListViewAdapter is calling...", "calling...");
        ViewHolder holder;
        Log.i("View to be converted", "" + convertView);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null);
            Log.i("View to be converted", "" + convertView);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.notes_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);

            holder.delete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_minus);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.notes_text.setText((String) list.get(position));

        holder.delete.setTag((Integer) position);

        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Integer myIntegerObject = new Integer((Integer) view.getTag());
                Log.i("Integer postioton", "" + myIntegerObject.intValue());

                list.remove(list.indexOf(list.get(myIntegerObject.intValue())));

                list_size = list.size();

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep a boolean flag to indicate edit mode. In `ListAdapter`'s `getView()` set `Button` visibility to `VISIBLE` or `GONE` depending on your boolean flag.

Now, to toggle all button visibility you have so change boolean flag, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter. This will re-draw all visible List Items.

add variable in adapter class:

```
boolean editmode = false;
```

In `getView()` :

```
holder.delete.setVisibility( (editmode ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE ) );
```

finally add a method to your adapter class:

```
public void setEditMode(boolean value){
  editmode = value;
  this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Can you please explore answer further more. I am getting this problem, I have a List and a Edit button on the top but when I am changing visibility of Delete button to visible which is in List item then list only show delete button in last row.